# Object detection with Keras - issue with combining training images and target masks

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, keras, object-detection

I'm fitting my keras model on a sample of images and their corresponding binary masks for object detection. Basically, I'm followig the example at the end of [this page](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# we create two instances with the same arguments

data_gen_args = dict(
                     rotation_range=4.,
                     width_shift_range=0.05,
                     height_shift_range=0.05,
                     shear_range=0.05,
                     zoom_range=0.05,
                     horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode='nearest')

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
seed = 2019
```

Now create generators for images and masks:

```
target_size = (180, 320)
small_target_size = (11,20)
batch_size = 8 

image_generator_trn = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path+'train',
    class_mode=None,
    target_size = target_size,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle= False,
    seed=seed)


mask_generator_trn = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path+'mask/train',
    class_mode=None,
    target_size = small_target_size,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle= False,
    seed=seed)
```

Outpu:

```
Found 3327 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 3327 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

Finally we create a generator to be used in `model.fit_generator`:

```
train_generator = zip(image_generator_trn, mask_generator_trn)
```

My problem is with the last line (zipping); i either get memory exception or it doesn't finish execution. I suspect it's trying to zip 2 infinite loops, and tried zipping lazy-ly in `model.fit_generator` but same issue.

What can i do differently?

Comment: Which `python` version do you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Comment: How did you structure your training directory? Did you create a subdirectory for each class and then copied each input image into these subdirectories?

Comment: @marcopah yes, but the issue was the zip and changing it to izip fix it. I ended up writing my own mixiterator will put the solution here when i have time. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in that `zip` tries to exhause both of the generators when they are designed to produce outputs infinitely. This is the reason behind this behaviour. In order to overcome this issue use `itertools.izip` function. Moreover - please notice that if you don't set the same `seed` for both generators - different augmentations would be applied to your `x` and `y` images. You need to either turn off random augmentation or set the same `seed`.

Comment: I'd appreciate upvoting my answer :)